# Trying to compile an XCode project with a workspace on Jenkins slave

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I got a Jenkins slave building single xcode projects, working perfectly.

However, I got a project with a workspace where some 3rd party files are setup in the root of the workspace with a gitmodule then imported in to the project [as described here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x).

When Jenkins compiles and reaches `AppDelegate.h` it throws and error when trying to import a file from the library.

```
fatal error: 'RestKit/Restkit.h' file not found #import <RestKit/Restkit.h>
```

I got the project compiling by pointing to the workspace. However it now fails when reaches the packaging stage. I don't see the build directory created in the workspace.

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Cannot remove *.ipa files from a non-existing directory:
 /Users/leon/Work/projects/wearehive/flatstr/build/Flatstr/dev/jenkins/workspace/Snug-debuOLD/build/Debug-iphoneos

 Packaging IPA
 FATAL: null
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder.perform(XCodeBuilder.java:421)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:705)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:475)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1434)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
```

Comment: Do you specify correctly where to look for headers? In other words, what are your `-I` options in the log say?

Comment: Could you elaborate please. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: XCode invokes a compiler (I believe it to be gcc) to compile your files. When compiler invocation is echoed to the console it contains, among other things, options that tell it where to look for imported/included headers. I think that option is `-I` (by analogy with C/C++ 'tradition'). Please inspect the contents of that option - it should contain your 3rdparty directory in order for includes to work. I suspect that it references it incorrectly.

Comment: I can see in the console the correct path.

Comment: OK, (1) is it an absolute path or relative path? Better yet, what exactly does it say? (2) Check that the code is actually found in the workspace.

Comment: Path:  -I/Users/leon/Work/projects/wearehive/flatstr/build/Flatstr/dev/jenkins/workspace/Snug-debuOLD/Flatstr/Flatstr/Build/Intermediates/RestKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/RestKit.build/DerivedSources/armv6  and it is found.

Comment: Just one last question before I declare myself stumped: your Jenkins build log almost at the very beginning contains words 'Building on <nodename> in workspace <workspacepath>'. What is <workspacepath>? Also, just to make sure no stone is left unturned, check that RestKit/Restkit.h is found in .../armv6

Comment: workspace: dev/jenkins/workspace/Snug-debuOLD the header is in the path. I can see Jankins checking out the gitmodule and compiling the lib. But when it comes to compile the AppDelegate, error thrown on the import. This is nutz..

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction here: if the workspace is what you say it is, then the directory specified in `-I` option probably does not exist (there would be no `/dev/jenkins` after `Flatstr` - `dev/jenkins` would be in your home directory). The only way it can be there if you run Jenkins from `Flatstr` as homedir.

Comment: Could you resolve this? I noticed that with Xcode 4.4, the build products folder need to be adjusted in Workspace Settings, but there are more subfolders generated not taken into account by Jenkins: /<project name>/<Build>/<Products>/

Answer (score 2):

Your Project=>build settings=>Header Search Paths, add follow path:

```
"$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build/Headers"
```

Be sure checked box in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use xcode plugin and use this for `SYMROOT` value instead of space fixes the problem.

`${workspace}/build/[app name]/Build/Products`